# Workflow 4.0 code activities calling other activites (persist, delay etc)

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I have a bunch of Workflow foundation 4.0 RC code activities that consume web services and talk to databases that I want to add some error handling in.

I would really like to be able to attempt to call my web service / db, catch any faults such as a communication failure and then retry the same operation in 1 hours time (after I have logged the exception).

Is there a way of doing something like this?

```
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context) {

  Persist(); // I would like to invoke the persist activity like this

  if (!AttemptServiceCall()) {

        // I would like to invoke a delay activity like this
        Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)); // wait 30 mins before trying again
        Execute(context); // call this activity again
  }
}

private bool AttemptServiceCall() {

  bool serviceCallSuccessful = true;

  try {
        myService.InvokeSomeMethod();
  }
  catch (CommunicationException ex) {
        myEventLogger.Log(ex);
        serviceCallSuccessful = false;
  }

  return serviceCallSuccessful;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is not difficult at all once you know how WF4 activities work.

I could type a long story but as Richard Blewett has already blogged about a Retry activity that does the exact retry action you describe I am just going to link to that blog post [here](http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,c3394709-1aaf-486a-8d1f-51050ce94ecc.aspx). The only thing missing is the persist but that should be easy to add.

Just create your AttemptServiceCall activity and add it as the body. Given that it sounds like a potentially long running action I would suggest using an AsyncCodeActivity as the base class.

Comment: Thanks for your swift answer once again Maurice - you are the workflow king!